# How to pack bit fields in short integer with a char array?

Tags: c, bit-fields, bit-packing

In the following 2 structures,

```
typedef struct _a {
    short a1:13 __attribute__((packed));
    char a2[4]  __attribute__((packed));
} a;

typedef struct _b {
    short b1:10 __attribute__((packed));
    short b2:10 __attribute__((packed));
    short b3:12 __attribute__((packed));
} b;
```

In `struct b`, I find that bits of b2 are packed with b1, and bits of b3 are packed with b2. It ultimately results in 4 byte value.

I was expecting the similar behaviour with `struct a` but I don't see the same. First 2 bytes are occupied with a1 (unused 5 bits) and following by 4 bytes for a2.

Is this behaviour expected? Why can't I pack the char[4] along with short:13? Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: This is not valid C code but some non-standard extension. Therefore, nobody can answer your question unless you state which compiler you are using.

Comment: What is invalid about it? I am on a standard linux box with gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20071124 (Red Hat 4.1.2-42).

Comment: @badman `__attribute__((packed))` is not standard C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Too long to be a comment, so i put it as an answer)

To pack all fields together, you must replace the array with 4 fields:

```
typedef struct _a {
    short a1:13 __attribute__((packed));
    char a2_0:8 __attribute__((packed));
    char a2_1:8 __attribute__((packed));
    char a2_2:8 __attribute__((packed));
    char a2_3:8 __attribute__((packed));
} a;
```

Comment: does it work for you? it doesn't work for me. i get the same warnings like before.

Comment: They must be bit fields. That was going to be my point but i forgot about this! Fixed now.

Answer (score 8):

`a2` is not a bit-field so it will never be put together with `a1`. The standard says

> Values stored in non-bit-field objects of any other object type
>   consist of n × CHAR_BIT bits, where n is the size of an object of that
>   type, in bytes. The value may be copied into an object of type
>   unsigned char [n] (e.g., by memcpy); the resulting set of bytes is
>   called the object representation of the value.

So such a sub-object *must* be an addressable unit, and there is not exception possible from that rule.

Comment: Thank you! You say that it's never possible which is acceptable because it is designed like that. I am trying to understand the reason for that. Why is there a restriction that the sub-object must be an addressable unit? Compiler should be able to figure out what my intention is. It doesn't sound very complex. Would you know why this restriction comes from?

Comment: @badmad, it is just simple, a type is supposed to be compatible across compilation units, all types that declare the same types of fields in the same order *must* behave the same. So the compiler cannot deduce that in no other compilation unit the address of such a wouldn't be taken. The idea of types is to define interfaces. And BTW, your first example is even such that the address must be usable. You define it as an array, in C the only reasonable way to use such a component is to use it in expressions that implicitly take the start address of that array.

Comment: Acceptable explanation, Jens! Thanks a lot!